# jQuery to change listbox selection mode

Tags: asp.net, jquery, listbox

I have an ASP.NET page with a listbox whose selection mode is set to multiple by default. I would like to set its selection mode to single on a button click.

Code snippet of my attempt:

```
$('#testBtn').click(function(){        
      $('#testListBox').attr("SelectionMode","Single");
});
```

It is not working though. What am I doing wrong here and how to get it to work?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select box uses the attribute "multiple" to determine if it should allow multiple selections. You can remove it via jQuery using the [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) function:

```
$('#testListBox').removeAttr('multiple');
```